# Generalizing The Cardinal Characteristics of the Continuum

Tags: set-theory

Has any work been done on generalizing any characteristics of the cardinality of the continuum?

The bounding number $\mathfrak{b}$ and dominating number $\mathfrak{d}$ could be easily generalized for ordinals $\alpha$, as follows:

$$\forall f,g\in\alpha^\alpha(f\leq_{\alpha}g\Leftrightarrow|\{\beta\in\alpha:f(\beta)>g(\beta)\}|<|\alpha|)$$
$$\mathfrak{b}_\alpha=\min\{|F|:F\subseteq\alpha^\alpha\land\forall f\in\alpha^\alpha\exists g\in F(g\not\leq_\alpha f)\}$$
$$\mathfrak{d}_\alpha=\min\{|F|:F\subseteq\alpha^\alpha\land\forall f\in\alpha^\alpha\exists g\in F(f\leq_\alpha g)\}$$

A few points to be  made at this point:

- $\mathfrak{b}_\alpha\leq\max\{|F|:F\subseteq\alpha^{\alpha}\}=|\alpha^\alpha|=2^{|\alpha|}$
- For cardinals $\kappa,\mathfrak{b}_\kappa>\kappa$ (this is shown by generalized diagonalization)
- The last two points combined make $\mathfrak{b}_\kappa=\kappa^+$ if $\kappa^+=2^\kappa$ (or if GCH is assumed)
- $\mathfrak{b}_\omega$ is clearly, in this case, $\mathfrak{b}$, and the same is true with $\mathfrak{d}_\omega$.

Comment: Yes, this is actually a very active area.

Comment: The introduction to "Sheva-Sheva-Sheva: Large Creatures"
 by Roslanowski and Shelah contains a lot of references.  To the best of my knowledge, a good and reasonably comprehensive survey of these matters is an "open exposition problem" in Set Theory...

The paper is available as number 777 at Shelah's archive: http://shelah.logic.at/files/777.pdf

Comment: I did not know that Shelah had an easily accessible paper archive. Thank you. Are there any other famous set theory mathematicians with similar archives?

Comment: See also [this paper by S.-D. Friedman](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/set.14.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don Monk has a paper describing generalized $\mathfrak b$ and $\mathfrak d$ as you describe. In his paper he further generalizes to $\mathfrak b_{\kappa,\lambda,\mu}$ (and analogously for $\mathfrak d$), considering families of functions in ${}^\lambda\mu$ with $\lambda, \mu,$ and $\kappa$ all possibly distinct. I think in his notation the numbers you describe are $\mathfrak b_{\alpha, \alpha, \alpha}$ and $\mathfrak d_{\alpha, \alpha, \alpha}$

[Generalized ${\frak b}$ and ${\frak d}$. Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 45 (2004), no. 3, 129--146.](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/monk75.pdf)